# Home lead testing kits

Tags: health-and-safety, lead

Are home lead testing kits accurate or should I hire a pro? What should I being looking for when purchasing home lead testing kits?

Comment: what exactly do you want to test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The home lead testing kits are very accurate if used properly, but only spot check.  I buy these same kits in boxes of 50 for home inspections.  If you are concerned about widespread lead, you need to have an electronic scan dome by a pro.  This type of electronic camera can detect lead in walls, trim, interior or exterior and can cover an entire house in half an hour.  Costs vary, but 200 to 300 bucks is average in my area.  If you are only concerned with a small area or certain surfaces, the home test is fine. There is a technique to it, don't want to over simplify, but not hard if you read and follow the directions carefully.  Good luck

Comment: I want to test some old trim that we found in the basement that matches the trim in the living room. They look original (from 1940s) and have many layers of paint on them. Also, I am concerned about possibility of lead near our old radiators and behind cabinets in kitchen.